# What's the best way to pass parameters to a function without tightly coupling with parameter type?

Tags: go, interface, reusability

I have two structs each with integer fields a, b. Now I want to write a function called sum which results a+b

```golang
type Type1 struct {
    a int64
    b int64
}

type Type2 struct {
    a int64
    b int64
}

func sum(details Type1) int64 {
    return details.a + details.b
}

func sum2(details Type2) int64 {
    return details.a + details.b
}

func main() {
    type1Obj: = Type1 {}
    type2Obj: = Type2 {}
    sum(type1Obj)
    sum2(type2Obj)
}
```

Actual : I am creating two functions for same behaviour, just because of type.

Expected : I need to solve the use case with help of single function.

Comment: `sum(a, b int64) int64`

Comment: The function `func sum(details struct{ a, b int64 }) int64 { return details.a + details.b }` works for the types in the question.

Comment: Interfaces are the normal way to define common behavior for different types. I assume your real use case is more complicated than your example, but for the example, you could define methods that get the `a` and `b` values and define an interface that includes those methods, and then write your `sum` function to take the interface type.

Comment: @CeriseLimón the approach suits smaller structs, but with greater functionality and more data members in the struct, wont that be messy ?

Comment: @mouryavenkat: Yes, the approach is not a good one for structs with a large number of members.  Like I said, it's a solution for the types in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use of an interface.

```
// There is some interface that expresses the behaviors you need
type Summable interface {
    A() int64
    B() int64
}

// And it can be summed
func sum(s Summable) int64 {
    return s.A() + s.B()
}
```

Then you can conform various types to Summable:

```
type Type1 struct {
    a int64
    b int64
}

// Type1 conforms to Summable
func (t Type1) A() int64 { 
    return t.a 
}

func (t Type1) B() int64 {
    return t.b
}

type Type2 struct {
    a int64
    b int64
}

// And so does Type2
func (t Type2) A() int64 { 
    return t.a 
}

func (t Type2) B() int64 {
    return t.b
}
```

And then you can sum any Summable type:

```
func main() {
    type1Obj := Type1 {}
    type2Obj := Type2 {}
    println(sum(type1Obj))
    println(sum(type2Obj))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qVQn9EURf4C)